# ChromeDriver won't start in fullscreen in headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

my problem is that Chrome won't start in fullscreen when it's in headless mode.
Running code in C#, ChromeDriver version: 87.0.4280.8800

I've tried "everything".

- Kiosk mode
- Set screen to like 800, 800

When running in headless I can see of GetScreenshot that Chrome is in like mobile view.
When running normally (not headless) Chrome starts fullscreen. I'm really stuck here.

```
public MyTestMethod() {
 
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();   
  options.AddArgument("--headless");   
  options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");   
  options.AddArguments("--test-type-auth-server-hitelist=*.myTestSite.test");    
  options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");   
  options.AddArgument("--allow-insecure-localhost");   
  options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");   
  options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");    
  WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - this did the trick if anyone else encounter this problem:

`enter code here`options.AddArgument("--window-size=1325x744");